# jboss clustering when one machine isn't big enough to run application

Tags: jboss

Im given a problem and am currently trying to come up with the best way to solve it. I have a few ideas, but one question about jboss clustering. keep in mind these applications were written very poorly, thats why they require so much memory and there is nothing i can do about that right now.

Now, I have clustered applications on Jboss where the application was small enough to run on one box. Meaning if i needed to, one machine could handle the load. But the current problem is that i have been asked to run several systems on the same environment. Our machines are virtuals and due to limited hardware, are restricted to 8 gigs of ram which gives jboss about 7 gigs to itself. That isn't enough to run the group of applications, Im constantly getting heap errors and crashes.

If i cluster 2 or 3 jboss instances together, can i run applications that consume more resources than a single box can handle?

Answer (score 0):

If 8 gigs is your memory limit it sounds like it might be time to re-evaluate your hosting platform. A decent server class machine can reliably handle upwards of 32gigs of ram and either vmware or hyper-v can each deliver more than 8 gigs to a VM.

TL;DR - Get a better box and reevaluate your virtualization platform.